# Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch on AddShape

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I created a Macro in Excel to place X's on a flow chart. My first version worked perfectly. Now, I am making modifications to the Excel document and I cannot get the Macro to run. I have checked various points to ensure there has been no change. I cannot determine why this won't run. The differences to the Excel document are as follows: (1) I created a Tab (let's call it VL) that has steps of a procedure. In that document, I use numerals (these are set to general format) for each step to indicate if it will be excluded from a process. (2) On a separate tab (let's call it ProcedureA), a user can pick steps of a procedure from a dropdown menu. (3) Based on the step chosen from the menu, an event macro pulls data into other columns of ProcedureA. The numerals I mention above are among the data pulled in and are also general format (this is based on column -161 below). The data that specifies where the X will be placed (XLeft, XTop, XWidth, XHeight) is in general format. I have taken the necessary steps to go through the code and determine which part of the macro is not working. The interesting this is that the macro will go through the first loop and place an X, but it fails on the 2nd loop. As you may guess, if the number pulled in is a 1,2, or 3, the color of the X will be different on the flow chart.  I have checked everything and I cannot determine why the macro is failing. Any help the group will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Sub ProcessACElim()
'
' ProcessACElim Macro


Dim ws1 As Sheet27
    Dim ws2 As Sheet2
    Dim shp As Shapes
    Dim XLeft As Variant, XTop As Variant, XWidth As Variant, XHeight As Variant
    
   Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheet27.Range("FZ4:GD24")
        
        
        XLeft = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
        XTop = rng.Offset(, 2).Value
        XWidth = rng.Offset(, 3).Value
        XHeight = rng.Offset(, 4).Value
   
        
        Select Case rng.Offset(, -161).Value
            Case "1"
                Set shp = Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeMathMultiply, XLeft, XTop, XWidth, XHeight)
                    With shp
                     .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                     .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                     .Name = "PA"
                     
                    End With
                    
                
            Case "2"
                Set shp = Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeMathMultiply, XLeft, XTop, XWidth, XHeight)
                         With shp
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        .Name = "PA"

                        End With
                        
            Case "3"
                Set shp = Sheet2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeMathMultiply, XLeft, XTop, XWidth, XHeight)
                         With shp
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                        .Name = "PA"
                        
                        End With
                
        End Select
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim shp As Shapes` should be `Dim shp As Shape` singular. Are you sure you want to loop through all the cells iwith `For Each rng In Sheet27.Range("FZ4:GD24")` .

Comment: I played around with  the Shape vs Shapes, but I don't think it made a difference. I will go back and try it again. As for the FZ to GD specification, users could write up to 20 steps for a process. The range specified will have the coordinates for where each X, if required will go. It does not seem to slow the macro down.

Comment: @CDP1802 Changed the shapes to shape. Did not work. Any other thoughts. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `AddShape` returns a [Shape object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Shapes.AddShape). I don't understand your loop, on second pass cell GA4.offset(0,1) will set xLeft to the value you used previously (FZ4) for xTop. I must be missing something I guess.

Comment: @CDP1802 First, it won't touch FZ4. I placed that there as a marker. Thus, 1 cell after, it grabs the Left start point from GA4, then the Top Start point from GB4, then Width (GC4) and Height(GD4).If it finds the numbers 1,2 or 3 in the column that is 161 places before FZ4, it will execute the shape. If no number, no shape. Then, it goes to the next row and starts again. I hope this does not sound condescending. That is not what I am trying for. I am trying to make sure I describe this adequately.  Again, this worked in version1, but not the new version. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to scan down the rows you need to use `Range("FZ4:FZ24")` You can still get the values from the other columns with offset. Use F8 and single step the program to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: @CDP1802 Thank you! This worked. It seems so strange to me because in the previous version, my method worked. Nonetheless, I can move forward. THank you so much for your help with this!